# I want to disable a button which is inside Arraylist button--eclipse for Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I wand to disable a button called(button1and12)  which is inside 
Arraylist by fetching the button1and12 from the Arraylist. 
I have done the coding but shows error in reterving the button from 
arraylist...Plz help me out to do it.

```
private ArrayList<Button> b1;
private Button DisableBtn;
private Button button1and12;
private Button button2and9;
private Button button3and5;

button1and12 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button2and9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
button3and5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

b1 = new ArrayList<Button>();
b1.add(button1and12);
b1.add(button2and9);
b1.add(button3and5);           

DisableBtn= b1.get(b1.indexOf(1));
DisableBtn.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.image3_5);
DisableBtn.setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Please show the stacktrace from logcat

Comment: It say source not found inthe line DisableBtn= b1.get(b1.indexOf(1));

Comment: While in debugging mode I found this error but the program runs but not fetching the index1 button from the Arraylist

Comment: try DisableBtn= b1.get(0); Remember `ArrayList` is zero based!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you've added that buttons into the list like this:

```
b1 = new ArrayList<Button>();
b1.add(button1and12);
b1.add(button2and9);
b1.add(button3and5);
```

So far no errors should appear! Now ...

- If you want to retrieve `n`th button, just try `b1.get(n);`
- If you want to retrieve index of a certain button, try `b1.indexOf(button);`
- Remove a button by its index => `b1.remove(n);`
- Remove a button by its reference => `b1.remove(button);`
- ...

Anyway, your `indexOf(1)` statement is not correct, `indexOf` method take one argument with type `Button` (in your case) not `int` .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use indexOf():

```
DisableBtn= b1.get(b1.indexOf(button1and12));
```

If you want to use index:

```
DisableBtn= b1.get(b1.get(0));
```